# Query using a summary table symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

There are my entities:

Order entity with property product

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * One Order has Many OrderProduct.
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderProduct", mappedBy="order")
 */
private $product;

/**
 * CatalogOrder constructor.
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->product = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

OrderProduct entity with properties product, order and number (this entity is needed to store the quantity of ordered products)

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CatalogOrder", inversedBy="product")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $order;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="order")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $product;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="number", type="integer")
 */
private $number;
```

Product entity with property order

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderProduct", mappedBy="product")
 */
private $order;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->order = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

I want to look for the name of the goods in the orders on the frontend, i.e. Enter "be" and displays all orders with the product "beer".

My guess is not true:

```
$qb->join('o.product', 'p')
    ->where('p.product.name LIKE :name')
    ->setParameter('name', '%'.$filters['productName'].'%');
```

Comment: What are you getting back that you are not receiving?  That is the proper way to use wildcards in your `LIKE` query.

Comment: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 82 near 'name LIKE :name': Error: Class Shleif\\CatalogBundle\\Entity\\OrderProduct has no field or association named product.name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see where your issue is now.  That is not how you deal with joined entities.  You need to also join the `Product` entity from `OrderProduct`. It should look like this:

```
$qb
    ->join('o.product', 'op')
    ->join('op.product', 'p')
    ->where('p.name LIKE :name')
    ->setParameter('name', '%'.$filters['productName'].'%')
;
```

You should really rename `$product` in your `Order` entity to be `$orderProduct` so it matches the actual entities, and becomes less confusing.  Once you do that your query will make more sense:

```
$qb
    ->join('o.orderProduct', 'op')
    ->join('op.product', 'p')
    ->where('p.name LIKE :name')
    ->setParameter('name', '%'.$filters['productName'].'%')
;
```

Comment: This throw error, beacause `'o.product', 'p'` link with `OrderProduct` entity, not with `Product` entity

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try in the evening

Comment: All perfectly! Thanks a lot for your help